# Can I access Gmail mails by POP3 and OAuth2 in Java application?

Tags: java, email, google-oauth, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am developing a Java application and I need to access Gmail mails. Till now, I am able to connect to Gmail IMAP server with OAuth mechanism. Now, I want to connect to Gmail POP3 server with OAuth mechanism. However, Google developer docs does not have any relevant information pertaining to POP3 with OAuth mechanism. So my question is:

**Is POP3 access to mails with OAuth mechanism is supported?**

If so, where is documentation for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported.

As stated in: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2.